# Character classes in notepad++ regex search

Tags: regex, notepad++

The following search works in notepad++ v. 7.5.9 on my laptop:

```
[[:space:]]
```

The same search does not produce any results in notepad++ v. 7.5.7 installed on the computer at work. Unless the classes of the form `[[:name:]]` were added in versions 7.5.8-7.5.9, what could explain this difference in behavior?

Comment: It works on my NPP 7.5.7. Did you check the regex checkbox? Also, note that NPP uses Boost regex libray, not PCRE, I removed the tag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I surely did.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this in [NPP community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/)?

Comment: [This page was last modified on 3 March 2014, at 16:07](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you for the suggestion. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17331/character-classes-don-t-work-for-me-in-v-7-5-7